# Typescript: Generate build error when enums are used in d.ts files

Tags: typescript, enums

enum in .d.ts files don't work (amd modules) and we get runtime errors, instead if we define as const enum they work.
Is there a compiler option we can use to generate a build error when enum is defined instead of const enum in d.ts files.

```
// foo.d.ts
enum Foo {
   Option1,
  Optino2
}
```

does not work and gives runtime error about missing module foo

```
// foo.d.ts
const enum Foo {
   Option1 = 0,
   Option2 = 1
}
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TSLint rule called [`prefer-const-enum`](https://github.com/ajafff/tslint-consistent-codestyle/blob/master/docs/prefer-const-enum.md).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just miss the `export` key word:

```
// foo.d.ts
export enum Foo {
   Option1,
   Optino2
}
```